# maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile(1 errors) in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I want to learn java spring, so I choose Eclipse Mars2 Version and I want to build a java project using Maven. But I get errors

```
maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile(1 errors)
maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile(1 errors)
```

Then I check my maven and java path in my Windows 10 64 bit system variable.
I configured like this :

```
JAVA_HOME => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71
M2_HOME => C:\apache-maven
MAVEN_HOME => C:\apache-maven
```

And in systen variabel path :
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin
    %M2_HOME%\bin

Everything is fine, I checked it by `java -version` and `mvn-version`
Also, I have installed mvn plugin in eclipse in `install new software`
to maven  :

Name: m2e
   Location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

But I still failed. The errors is still pop up.
Please advise. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I test to build a project maven-archetype-quickstart version 1.1

```
execution default-compile, in Access/pom.xml
execution default-testCompile, in Access/pom.xml
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.tresnamuda</groupId>
  <artifactId>access</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>access</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Eclipse detect error in first line which is :
     project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  .....

also in line 8.

This is the complete error :

[image: Eclipse mars2 errors]

Comment: Exactly what errors?

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: If you getting only getting started then perhaps it would be easier to use the spring tool suite - https://spring.io/tools/sts.

Comment: I'm not sure that update helps. It says `(1 errors)`, but `execution default-compile, in Access/pom.xml` does not look like an error.

Comment: You still didn't post the actual content of the errors. What are they?

Comment: The error "failure to transfer ..." is the real problem here. You need to check if your connection to Maven central is working ...or if you have proxy problem..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is corruption in your local repository. 
Please try:

- Delete the local repository, if you use Windows, delete the folder  `C:\Users\your-user-name\.m2\repository`
- In Eclipse, right click on the project name and click Maven\Update project ... (or use hotkey ALT+F5)